# Channel members are not getting updated

Tags: javascript, discord.js

*I'm using **discord.js v13**.*

I want to disconnect all members from a voice channel. Using `interaction.guild.channels.fetch()`, I'm able to get voice channels and the members' information.

But when I switch the voice channel, the data is still wrong because it's **not updating.**

This is my code:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const { commandName } = interaction;

  switch (commandName) {
    case 'channels':
      const channelInput = interaction.options.getString('channelname');
      const channelExist = (await interaction.guild.channels.fetch()).find(channel => {
        return channel.name == channelInput && channel.isVoice()
      })
      
      if (!channelExist) {
        await interaction.reply('no voice channel');
        break;
      }
      console.log(channelExist.members)
      console.log('===========')

      break;
  }
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To receive updates from voice channels on who is joining and leaving which channels you need to supply you `client` with the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent. That will allow your data to update.