# Discord.js: channels.fetch() returns outdated data

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I am trying to get all members of guild, that currently in any voice channel for every minute. But channels.fetch() always provides not actual data, but data that it retrieves at the moment of the client.login

```
import { getConfig } from '../config/config';
import { client } from '../client';
import { CronJob } from 'cron';
import { EmbedBuilder, GuildMember, TextChannel } from 'discord.js';

const checkerVoice = async () => {
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(getConfig().guild);

  const log = (await guild.channels.fetch(getConfig().channels.text.log.debug)) as TextChannel;

  const channels = await guild.channels.fetch();
  const voices = channels.filter(
    (channel) => channel.type === 2 && channel.id !== getConfig().channels.voice.afk,
  );

  voices.forEach(async (channel) => {
    const voice = await guild.channels.fetch(channel.id);
    const members = voice.members as unknown as GuildMember[];
    for (const member of members) {
      log.send({
        embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(`${channel.id}@${member}}`)],
      });
    }
  });
};

export const voiceCron = new CronJob('* * * * *', checkerVoice);
```

tried to get channels data with channels.fetch() and channels.cache, different caching options of the client, fetching channels at the top of the function to update cache. None of that works for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot doesn't detect if the user is in a voice channel! || Discord.JS V.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961000/bot-doesnt-detect-if-the-user-is-in-a-voice-channel-discord-js-v-14)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros as I mentioned below, yes, absolutely

Comment: It was an automated message as I voted to close this question as a duplicate :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was googling several days to resolve it, but found the answer in related questions right after I posted this question, which I could not find before. [Channel members are not getting updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460186/channel-members-are-not-getting-updated?rq=2)
The thing was in gateway intents, should add GuildVoiceStates to allow client retrieve voice states updates